# My-Sql Group concat with concat

Tags: mysql

I am using below query for fetching data but i am getting truncated result

```
SELECT group_concat(concat(`cl`.`payment_info`, '<=>', `cl`.`total_amount`) SEPARATOR '<==>') AS payment_info

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [payment_info] => [{"payment_date":"12\/12\/2016","payment_percentage":"30.00","payment_status"
:"Paid"},{"payment_date":"13\/12\/2016","payment_percentage":"20.00","payment_status":"Unpaid"},{"payment_date"
:"","payment_percentage":"","payment_status":"Unpaid"},{"payment_date":"","payment_percentage":"","payment_status"
:"Unpaid"},{"payment_date":"","payment_percentage":"","payment_status":"Unpaid"}]<=>0.00<==>[{"payment_date"
:"12\/12\/2016","payment_percentage":"50.00","payment_status":"Paid"},{"payment_date":"13\/12\/2016"
,"payment_percentage":"40.00","payment_status":"Unpaid"},{"payment_date":"","payment_percentage":"","payment_status"
:"Unpaid"},{"payment_date":"","payment_percentage":"","payment_status":"Unpaid"},{"payment_date":"","payment_percentage"
:"","payment_status":"Unpaid"}]<=>548.43<==>[{"payment_date":"12\/12\/2016","payment_percentage":"30
.00","payment_status":"Paid"},{"payment_date":"13\/12\/2016","payment_percentage":"20.00","payment_status"
:"Unpaid"},{"payment_date":"","payment_percentage":"","payment_status":"
        )

)
```

I am facing this issue when data is huge, else this query works fine please tell where i am making mistake.

In payment info json format data is saved while in amount, amount is saved. payment_info datatype is text

Answer (score 0):

You must set the **group_concat_max_len**. the default lenght is 1024 chars. see manual info

**group_concat_max_len**

```
Description: Maximum length in bytes of the returned result for a GROUP_CONCAT() function.
Commandline: --group-concat-max-len=#
Scope: Global, Session
Dynamic: Yes
Data Type: numeric
Default Value: 1024
Range - 32-bit: 4 to 4294967295
Range - 64-bit: 4 to 18446744073709547520
```